# How (and whether) to modify the object in a Chai BDD chain

Tags: chai

I am using [ChaiJS](http://chaijs.com/) with my [Casper-Chai](https://github.com/brianmhunt/casper-chai) plugin, and I am not sure how to go about a particular issue I am encountering.

I would like to be able to write tests such as:

```
expect(casper).selector("#waldo").to.be.visible;
```

This is pretty straightforward, with a call such as

```
utils.addChainableMethod(chai.Assertion.prototype, 'selector', 
  selectorMethod, selectorChainableMethod);

utils.addMethod(chai.Assertion.prototype, 'visible', visibleMethod);
```

Where the `*Method` references are to functions that perform respective tests or chainable calls.

My question is what is the best way to have e.g. 'selector' modify descendants in the chain. Two options come to mind:

1. use `utils.flag(chai, 'object')` to change it to the selector; or
2. create a new flag with e.g. `utils.flag(chai, 'casper-selector')`

When 'visible' is called, it can read the respective flag. Where modifying the 'object' seems to be useful is when calling e.g. 'length' later-on. However, I am concerned somewhat about unexpected side-effects of changing the 'object'.

I may also want to modify the object, for 'length' tests, down the chain, such as:

```
// there can be only one!
expect(casper).selector("#waldo").length(1)

// but that one has 4 classes
expect(casper).selector("#waldo").class.to.have.length(4)
```

Grateful for any thoughts and input.

---- **EDIT** ----

Okay, so here is the conceptual challenge that gave root to Casper-Chai, that requires a bit of a description of what Casper is and why Casper-Chai should be a Chai plugin and not just an alternative to the existing Casper API. Casper is a wrapper around the PhantomJS headless web browser, and as such Casper runs two effectively two distinct virtual machines: A 
"Controller" and a headless web browser.

There is no DOM or "document" or "window" object in the controller; the Controller is in this respect a lot like Node.js, albeit using the WebKit javascript parser. In parallel, PhantomJS starts a headless web browser. The Controller can then communicate through a PhantomJS/Casper API to the headless browser. The Controller can tell the headless browser what pages to load, what javascript to run (which is like typing javascript into the console), and even mimic events such as keyboard input and mouse clicks. The headless browser has a full DOM and javascript stack: it is a web-page loaded in WebKit. You can [capture screenshots](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.capture) of what WebKit would render.

Casper-Chai is run in the Controller. Tests created in Mocha + Chai in the Controller are meant to evaluate against the state of the headless browser. Although we can copy state from the browser to the Controller and run tests on that copied state, my limited experimentation with that design revealed problems inherent to the design (i.e. efficiency, race conditions, performance, and potential side-effects). The problem is that the browser state is dynamic, complex, and can be unwieldy.

So taking John's example, `expect(casper.find("#waldo")).to.be.visible` would not work, since there is no DOM, unless the object returned by Casper did some sort of lazy evaluation/mediation. Even if we serialized and copied the HTML element there there is no CSS in the Controller. Then, even if there were CSS for `#waldo`, there is no way to test the hierarchy as if it were a web-browser. We would have to copy a substantial portion of the DOM and all the CSS and then replicate a web-browser to test whether `#waldo` is visible - for every single test. Casper-Chai is meant to avoid this problem by running the tests in the browser.

Just for a little extra illumination, a trivial comparison is getting the number of elements that match a selector. One could write `expect(casper.evaluate(function () {return __utils__.findAll('.my_class')}).to.have.length(4)`, where `casper.evaluate` runs the given function in the headless browser and returns a list of DOM elements matching the selector as strings; and you can think of `__utils__` as Casper's version of jQuery. Alternatively, one could write `expect(casper).selector('.my_class').to.have.length(4)` where `selector` becomes the 'object' and it has a getter `.length` that calls 'casper.evaluate(function () { return **utils**.findAll('.my_class').length`. Only the integer length is returned. For a short number of tests either works fine, but for larger numbers of tests this performance characteristic becomes impactful (here, in this simplistic form, and potentially to a substantially greater extent in more complex cases).

One could of course write `expect(casper.evaluate(function () { __utils__.findAll('.my_class').length }).equal(4)`, but if one is going to write tests like this, why bother with BDD/Chai? It eliminates the benefit of readability that Chai offers.

It is also worth noting that there may be multiple Casper instances in the Controller, corresponding to multiple PhantomJS pages. Think of them as spooky tabs.

So given Domenic's answer that modifying the 'object' flag is the appropriate way to go about it, this seems the most practical way - subject to any thoughts in light of the above description.

I hope the above describes why Casper-Chai should be a plugin and not just an API extension to Casper. I'll also run this by Casper's author to see if he has any input.

It may not be a perfect relationship, but I am hopeful that Casper & Chai can get along handily. :)

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty stems from the fact that casper has a highly procedural API, with methods like `Casper#click(String selector)` and `Casper#fetchText(String selector)`. To fit naturally with chai, an object-oriented API is needed, e.g. `Casper#find(String selector)` (returning a `CasperSelection` object), `CasperSelection#click()`, `CasperSelection#text()`, etc.

Therefore I suggest you [extend the casper object itself](http://casperjs.org/extending.html) with a `find` or `selector` method which returns an object on which you can base your assertions. Then you will not need to change the object flag.

```
expect(casper.find("#waldo")).to.be.visible;
expect(casper.find("#waldo")).to.have.length(1)
expect(casper.find("#waldo").class).to.have.length(4)
```

Comment: Thanks @John - that's a good thought, and certainly a possibility

Comment: I made an edit (sorry for the length) to the question that describes the rationale for a plugin. I think what you are suggesting may still be a be a better option than modifying 'object'; the question may be whether we inject a mediator into the Chai chain (that needn't be lazy) or Casper has a native lazy mediator. I have to think about it some more. :)

Comment: Thanks muchly John. I really like that idea, especially after reading your Chai-jQuery plugin code. I was just mulling over whether it may be better to have an e.g. `casper.$` that wraps remote jQuery calls, and then we can use your Chai-jQuery plugin to test the results. Here's a gist of what the wrapper might look like (CoffeeScript): https://gist.github.com/4365815

Answer (score 1):

I mostly agree with @John. You're performing your expectations on some other object, so saying

```
expect(casper).select("#waldo").to.have.length(1)
```

is very strange. You're not expecting anything about `casper`, you're expecting something about `casper.find("#waldo")`. Consider also the `should` syntax:

```
casper.should.select("#waldo").have.length(1)
// vs.
casper.find("#waldo").should.have.length(1)
```

---

That said, if you're dead set on this kind of API, this is exactly what the `object` flag is for. Chai even does this, to make assertions like

```
myObj.should.have.property("foo").that.equals("bar")
```

work well:

https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/49a465517331308695c3d8262cdad42c3ac591ef/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L773

Comment: Thanks Domenic. I am glad to hear that the 'object' flag is meant for this purpose. I made an edit to the question that may give a little insight into the issue ... but I am thinking what you and John have suggested may be the best option. With a proper mediator, does it mean we wouldn't need a Casper-Chai plugin at all? :)

Comment: I think the key here is the semantic meaning of the two styles you're considering. In particular, my example of the `should` syntax helps make clear the problems with the first approach.

As for whether a Casper-Chai plugin is desirable at all, that depends on whether you want custom assertions or not. For example, @John's Chai-jQuery has some really lovely custom assertions, so if there are similar domain-specific ones for Casper, then it would make sense to build the plugin.

Comment: Thanks Dominic. I was just mulling over the need for custom assertions. There probably are some, and in any case the semantics of some native tests (e.g. 'match') are different for selectors, so I may have to consider overwriting them to test for selectors. I think Chai-jQuery is a good precedent, thanks - I'll peruse what @John has done there.